# MS Access VBA - somehow not getting OpenArgs passed, always NULL

Tags: vba, ms-access, parameters, openform

This seems like a really simple thing to do, and I believe I'm coding it correctly - but I get me.openargs as NULL for some reason.

**Calling code in a button click event on form1:**

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmGetLetter", , , , , , "CA14-09"

End Sub
```

**Form Open event on the called code:**

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
    strLetterName = Me.OpenArgs
Else
    strLetterName = "MISC-02"
End If
```

me.Openargs is always NULL - what am I missing here?

Comment: Are you making sure the form is closed before this is called?

Comment: Try `Form_Load()` instead.

Comment: Both Open and Load events work for me. If form 2 is already open, OpenForm command will execute but OpenArgs will not be populated and Load and Open events do not execute anyway.

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate the problem; your code works on my machine.  I suggest the microsoft fix of rebuilding the forms from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for the answers Erik A and June7, the issue was that I already had the form open when I was calling it! I did not know of that quirk.

Answer (score 0):

As Erik A and June7 suspected, I had the form I was calling already open. Everything works as expected if I DoCmd.Openform without it being opened previously.

Many thanks!